# Flink Operator pods resources request and limits

Tags: kubernetes, resources, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm

Hi I am using flink operator version 1.3.1.
The way to configure the job and task mangers resources is like this

```yaml
spec:
    jobManager:
        resource:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 1G

    taskManager:
        resource:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 1G
```

In the crd schema I see that the only available elements I can configure is cpu(number), ephermalStorage(string), memory(string)

For correct usage of resources in our k8s cluster we want to be able to use k8s resources limit.

In searching of the FlinkDeployment schema I found under 'podTemplate' option to configure pod resources but it didn't work

```yaml
flinkConfiguration:
    jobmanager.memory.flink.size: 2g
    taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 2g
jobManager:
    podTemplate:
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: flink-main-container
                  resources:
                      limits:
                          cpu: '3'
                          memory: 3Gi
                      requests:
                          cpu: '1'
                          memory: 1Gi
taskManager:
    podTemplate:
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: flink-main-container
                  resources:
                      limits:
                          cpu: '3'
                          memory: 3Gi
                      requests:
                          cpu: '1'
                          memory: 1Gi
```

When the FlinkDeployment above was created without 'flinkConfiguration' I got error in my flink operator controller telling me to add this configuration.

After adding the 'flinkConfiguration' The deployment worked but the pods didn't had the correct resources

He had the following specs

```yaml
spec:
    containers:
      - resources:
            limits:
                cpu: '1'
                memory: 2560Mi
            requests:
                cpu: '1'
                memory: 2560Mi
```

It's seems that my request and limit was ignored and the memory was changed according to the 'flinkConfiguration' values.

Is there any way to use flink operator to deploy pods with requests and limits?